# Is there any good open source image dataset generation software?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I'm looking for services or scripts that can help to generate images for computer vision machine learning tasks. Not something like [this](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-create-a-synthetic-dataset-for-computer-vision/) where they just put together several layers of objects over other objects but more a like a 3D generation of objects in different environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box solution where you can create arbitrary objects and environments but if you are fine using Blender, [here is an example](https://github.com/christian-vorhemus/procedural-3d-image-generation) how you can use Blender to automatically create images as a training set for machine learning algorithms.